# How to peg a token to another token

Tags: wrapped-tokens, two-way-pegged

I want to create a token that represent the other token, the peg is not 1:1 but e.g. 10:1, so if a person deposit 1 of TokenX will get 10 of my tokens.
The person should also be able to withdraw his tokens and I must not be able to control the deposits.

More accurate example
if someone deposits 1 USDC will get 10 Tokens and this is always fixed

I don't know if this is possible, I thought cloning the WETH contract and change it a bit but I feel the deposit feature works only with ETH not with tokens

Comment: of course it is possible, you just have to track all deposits to USDC and immediately issue your own transaction after each block to `mint`/`burn` your own tokens accordingly and assign them to addresses. The users obviously won't control anything and couldn't withdraw your tokens or deposit, because your tokens are pegged to USDC. Users would increase/decrease their holding in your token by managing USDC tokens.

Comment: The UK tried to do this in the 90s and it didn't go well when Soros & friends spotted  the mistake

Answer (score 1):

Untested quick example to show you how the concept works:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

interface IUSDC {
  transferFrom(address, address, uint)
}

contract peggedToken is ERC20 {
  address usdcContract = 0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48;
  
  constructor ERC20("PeggedToken", "PT") {
  }

  function getPeggedToken(uint usdcIn) {
    IUSDC(usdcContract).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), usdcIn);
    _mint(msg.sender, usdcIn*10);
  }
}
```

This is the basic idea. User will need to make an `approve` call to the USDC contract directly, first, with the amount of `usdcIn`, and the address of this contract.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `approve` + `transferFrom` combination. So it would work something like this:

1. User adds your contract allowance to withdraw 10 of his tokenA (with the `approve` function)
2. User calls your contract's `exchange` function (or whatever it's called). This function: a) withdraws the 10 tokenA from user's wallet (`transferFrom`) and b) sends 1 tokenB to the same user's wallet.

And vice versa, for the reverse.

Comment: this is not what allowance feature was designed to. What if he wants to give infinite allowance to the contract? this way of working would fail

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure if I understand your comment correctly. I thought this is exactly what allowance was designed for - a two-phase transfer. And if one wants to allow more, nothing stops you from allowing the maximum `uint` can store. For security purposes you should never allow more than you want for the other to take - but in reality most services add way too much services for convenience reasons